# python_submit : command not found

Tags: condor

I was trying to run a simple python job using `HTCondor` refereing to [this tutorial link](https://condor.liv.ac.uk/commands/) but upon using the command

```
python_submit myjob.txt
```

This error occurs

```
python_submit : command not found
```

My job file (myjob.txt) is

```
python_script = myjob.py
indexed_input_files = myinput
indexed_output_files = myoutput
indexed_stdout = mystdout
indexed_stderr = mystderr
indexed_log = mylog
total_jobs = 10
```

My python file is

```py
import time

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this or does anyone knows about some better resource that I may use in order to understand the topic better. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tutorial is referring to wrapper scripts by ULiv. You should use condor_submit and specify a submit file like ( alternatively use the official python bindings in order to carry out similar task):

```
universe = vanilla
executable = /usr/bin/python
arguments = myjob.py
should_transfer_files = YES
transfer_input_files = myjob.py
output= myoutput
queue
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need an answer to why the command python_submit isn't working. But thanks for an alternative : )

Comment: This python_submit command was written by folks at the University of Liverpool.  If you aren't there, you won't have access to this script.  If you are there, well, you'll need to ask them...